# regexp_extract insert new row for each comma

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have this table and it has a column with multiple values separated by commas. I need to be able to separate the comma values and make a separate row out of it.

```
SELECT * FROM the_table

customer_id        customer_value
     1               aaa,bbb,ccc
     2               ddd,ggg,ttt,lll
     3               ppp,nnn,mmm,kkk,fff
```

I do not know if `regexp_extract` is the right function to use here but I am unable to create a new row.

```
SELECT *,
regexp_extract(customer_value,"^(?:[^,]*,){0}([^,]*)(?:[^,]*,){1}([^,]*)",1) as value_1,
regexp_extract(customer_value,"^(?:[^,]*,){0}([^,]*)(?:[^,]*,){1}([^,]*)",2) as value_2
FROM the_table

customer_id        customer_value            value_1          value_2
     1               aaa,bbb,ccc              aaa               bbb
     2               ddd,ggg,ttt,lll          ddd               ggg
     3               ppp,nnn,mmm,kkk,fff      ppp               nnn
```

What I am looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table

customer_id        customer_value               customer_value_comma
     1               aaa,bbb,ccc                      aaa
     1               aaa,bbb,ccc                      bbb
     1               aaa,bbb,ccc                      ccc
     2               ddd,ggg,ttt,lll                  ddd
     2               ddd,ggg,ttt,lll                  ggg
     2               ddd,ggg,ttt,lll                  ttt
     2               ddd,ggg,ttt,lll                  lll.........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your SQL:

```
SELECT 
 *, 
 explode( -- turn array into rows
  split(customer_value, ",") -- make an array
  as customer_value_comma -- rename column
 )
FROM the_table
```

Here's it in pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode, col
data = [(1,"aaa,bbb,ccc"),
(2,"ddd,ggg,ttt,lll"),
(3,"ppp,nnn,mmm,kkk,fff")]
df  = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(["customer_id","customer_value"])

 df.withColumn("cust_value_array",explode(split(col("customer_value"),","))).show()
```

Comment: thanks this is Gold. This works greats.